# TypeError: . The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, image, flask, jinja2, typeerror

view.py file

Since im new to flask. kindly help me out with this query

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
Migrate(app, db)
```

```
@view.route('/upload_image', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_image():
    form = upload_form()
    id = current_user.id
    name_to_update = Users.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method =='POST':
        name_to_update.image = request.files['image']
        Pic_filename = secure_filename(name_to_update.image.filename)
        pic_name = str(uuid.uuid1()) + '_' + Pic_filename
        saver = request.files['image']
        name_to_update.image = pic_name
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            saver.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD FOLDER'], pic_name))
            flash('user profile updated successfully')
            return render_template('account.html', form=form, name_to_update=name_to_update)
        except:
            flash('something is not working')
            return render_template('account.html', form=form)
```

this is my account.html. i'm trying to get profile image of user and saving it to displaying in profile.

```
<div class="profile-content">
  <div class="profile-contentimg">
        <div>
           <img src="static/img/apple.png" alt="" id="blah">
        </div>
        <form methods='POST' action="{{ url_for('view.upload_image') }}" class="dropzone">
           <div class="profileupload">
              <input type="file" name="filename" id="imgInp" >
              <a href="" class="text-white"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">upload</button>
           </div>
        </form>
  </div>
```

being beginner in programming with flask anything could be wrong.

Comment: If `request.method` is not equal to "POST", the function ends without returning anything, and thus returns `None` by default.  Presumably you need to add code that handles the case where `request.method` is "GET".

Comment: Either that, or add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` tag.

Comment: @TimRoberts I never knew, or long since forgot, that forms default to GET.

Comment: Then update the question to show the code you are now using and the whole traceback you see.

Comment: hi and welcome, please share error logs.

Comment: hey! I edited my view.upload function now now its giving me BAD request in local view 
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022 10:54:20] "GET /static/img/icons/chat.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 
127.0.0.1 -  [02/Dec/2022 10:54:20] "GET /static/img/icons/profile.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022 10:54:20] "GET /static/img/icons/contacts.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022 10:54:20] "GET /static/img/icons/settings.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022 10:54:20] "GET /static/img/icons/logout.svg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2022 10:54:26] "POST /upload_image HTTP/1.1" 400

Comment: while checking with print() im getting it upto POST request after that its not calling ?

Comment: You have a typo in your form code: `methods='POST'` should be `method='POST'`, with the typo, your form have no method, so you end up with a GET request, as raised by @JohnGordon